# how do I get my add to cart button to work in React (cart is not iterable) issue comes up in console?

Tags: reactjs, function

When I click my add to cart button on the page it comes up with the error 'cart is not iterable' in console not sure what Im doing wrong as Im not sure I really understand the error. I have a separate shop and cart page. The shop has ad addtoCart button which works Thanks in Advance.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Product.css';
import './Imagegallery.js';


export default function Product(product, cart, setCart){



const prod=product


const addToCart = (product) => {
let newCart = [...cart];
let itemInCart = newCart.find(
 (item) => prod.product.name === item.name
);
if (itemInCart) {
 itemInCart.quantity++;
} else {
 itemInCart = {
   ...product,
   quantity: 1,
 };
 newCart.push(itemInCart);
 }
 setCart(newCart);
 };



 return (
 <>
  <h1>Product Page</h1>
  <div className="products">
    <div className="product">
    <h3>{prod.product.name}</h3>
    <h4>£{prod.product.cost}</h4>
      <p>{prod.product.description}</p>
      <br />
        <button onClick={() => addToCart(product)}>
          Add to Cart
        </button>
        <section>
   <div className="image-gallery">
  <img className="gallery-highlight" img src={prod.product.image} alt=. 
 {prod.product.name} />
 <div className="image-preview">
    <img src={prod.product.image2} className="image-active" />
    <img src={prod.product.image3} />

<br />

    </div>

    </div>
</section>
</div>
</div>
</>
);
}
```

Comment: props are to be destructured like so Product( { product, cart, setCart } ). add curly braces around props variables.

Comment: when I do that the page completely disappears and it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') in console

Comment: I think you already assign product to prod `prod=product` so you should try `prod.name` instead of `prod.product.name`

Comment: just tried that and theres no difference to  the cart interable and if I do that for the <h> and <p> tags they disappear

Comment: on which line you are getting this error

Comment: it starts at the     let newCart = [...cart];    next one is the actual button. The other errors seem to mention react-dom